# Tem como usar CSHTML (Razor) em projetos ASPX WebForm?

Tags: c#, webforms, razor, aspx

Eu estava dando uma olhada [nessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264852/can-we-use-razor-syntax-in-asp-net-webforms-aspx-pages) no Stackoverflow Inglês, porque eu realmente acho muito confuso usar os arquivos ASPX e acho a sintaxe do Razor mais amigável.

Ao tentar adicionar um arquivo com a extensão `.cshtml` o projeto para fazer testes, eu tive um erro no sistema:

> Could not determine which version of ASP.NET Web Pages to use.
>
> In order to use this site, specify a version in the site’s web.config file. For more information, see the following article on the Microsoft support site: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254126
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Could not determine which version of
>   ASP.NET Web Pages to use.
>
> In order to use this site, specify a version in the site’s web.config
>   file. For more information, see the following article on the Microsoft
>   support site: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254126]
>   System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode.StartCore(IFileSystem
>   fileSystem, String appDomainAppPath, String binDirectory,
>   NameValueCollection appSettings, IEnumerable`1 loadedAssemblies,
>   IBuildManager buildManager, Action`1 loadWebPages, Action
>   registerForChangeNotification, Func`2 getAssemblyNameThunk) +16236
>   System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode.StartCore()
>   +167    System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode.Start() +38
>
> [InvalidOperationException: O método de inicialização do
>   pré-carregamento da aplicação Start no tipo
>   System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode emitiu uma
>   Exceção com a seguinte mensagem de erro: Could not determine which
>   version of ASP.NET Web Pages to use.
>
> In order to use this site, specify a version in the site’s web.config
>   file. For more information, see the following article on the Microsoft
>   support site: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254126.]
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1
>   methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures) +615
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1
>   methods) +141
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String
>   preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +102
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +157
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager
>   appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory
>   configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters,
>   PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +549
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): O método de inicialização do
>   pré-carregamento da aplicação Start no tipo
>   System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.PreApplicationStartCode emitiu uma
>   Exceção com a seguinte mensagem de erro: Could not determine which
>   version of ASP.NET Web Pages to use.
>
> In order to use this site, specify a version in the site’s web.config
>   file. For more information, see the following article on the Microsoft
>   support site: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254126.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +10085804
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +95
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest
>   wr, HttpContext context) +254

Eu gostaria de saber se realmente é possível substituir os arquivos `ASPX` por CSHTML.

Comment: acho que é tipo usar um .vb e tentar compilar como .cs

Comment: resumidamente não .... coisa diferentes, fazem diferente e tem propostas diferentes.

Comment: Botei `<add key="webPages:Version" value="2.0"/>` e o projeto tá funcionando agora. E exibindo o conteúdo...